# Create timeline from overlapping dates

Tags: oracle, date, range, analytics

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE positions
   (    "EMP_ID" CHAR(10 BYTE), 
    "GTYPE" NUMBER, 
    "AMT" NUMBER, 
    "START_DATE" DATE, 
    "STOP_DATE" DATE
   )
```

and this data:

```
 Insert Into positions (Emp_Id,Gtype,Amt,Start_Date,Stop_Date)
   select 'XA0022',1,1000,'01-MAY-2010','08-MAY-2012' from dual union
   Select 'XA0022',1,1000,'01-MAY-2010','31-DEC-2012' From Dual Union
   Select 'XA0022',2,500,'03-APR-2012','15-JUL-2012' From Dual Union
   Select 'XA0022',1,421,'01-MAY-2012','23-MAY-2012' From Dual Union
   Select 'XA0022',1,1514,'09-MAY-2012','31-DEC-2012' From Dual union
   select 'XA0022',1,600,'24-MAY-2012','24-MAY-2012' from dual;
```

How do I get to this:

```
from            to          type1   type2
   01-May-2010  02-Apr-2012     2000    0
   03-Apr-2012  30-Apr-2012     2000    500
   01-May-2012  07-May-2012     2421    500
   08-May-2012  08-May-2012     2421    500
   09-May-2012  22-May-2012     2935    500
   23-May-2012  23-May-2012     2935    500
   24-May-2012  15-Jul-2012     3114    500
   16-Jul-2012  31-Dec-2012     3014    0
```

Note: The amount is in effect on the start_date and is not in effect the day after the stop_date.

Any pointers gratefully received!

Comment: Can you extrapolate a little more?  I'm not understanding how the type1, type2 play into it.

Comment: I think the type1, type2 is not the trickiest bit.

What I have as source data is a table with a start and end date with an amount 

Some of these start / stop dates overlap

What I need is to be able to deduce is the total amount per type that is in effect each time a position starts or stops.

Think of it as a time line.

From 01-May-2010 to 02-Apr-12 total type1 = 2000, type2=0

This is because there are 2 x type 1s starting on the 01-May-10, but this changes on 03-Apr-12 as a type2 starts, so the type1 = 2000, type2=0 ends on the previous day 02-Apr-12

Comment: I think this is the pseudo code of what I want (ignoring the type1,2 thing for now)`code`
case when least((following_rows.start_date-1),following_rows.end_date) between current_row.start_date and current_row.stop_date then least((following_rows.start_date-1),following_rows.end_date)
else
current_row.end_date
end
`code`
I can't get a partition window to work as I want or make the distinction between the current row values and the following rows.

Comment: An idea, edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle's pivot.

[Oracle Pivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

```
select * from
(select emp_id, gtype, amt, start_date, stop_date
from positions)
pivot (sum(amt) as amt for (gtype) in (1 as "TYPE1", 2 as "TYPE2"))
order by emp_id, start_date;
```

With some more information (thanks), something like this?

```
select emp_id, gtype, start_date, 
case when next_amt <> amt then next_start_date -1 end as to_date
from
(select emp_id, gtype, start_date, amt,
lead(start_date,1) over (order by emp_id, start_date) next_start_date,
lead(amt,1) over (order by emp_id, start_date) next_amt
from
positions)
```

Comment: Not quite. I need to derive a timeline with a start, stop date with the amount in effect between those 2 dates. compare the first line of the desired output with the source date that starts on 01-May-2010.